# excel 2010 vba image logo swap switch

Tags: excel, vba, image

Have several logo images (similarly sized) inserted on a resources sheet. Need a way for users to easily select which company they want, and have that logo replace the default logo in upper left corner of several sheets.

Want to use a dropdown menu, have used dynamically before with great results. Dropdown can be in a userform or on just out on dashboard sheet. I already looked as stacking logos and trying a z-axis switch but Excel doesn't seem to support this. I've also tried .Replace and .Copy.

Again, logos are already pasted into a resource sheet that gets hidden, so I don't want users to go hunt down an image directory nor rely on an internet connection to fetch the image (they sometimes work offline). A default image is already emplaced in upper left corners, just need a way to match their (text) company selection to the corresponding logo image/name, and then switch the old logo with new on one several pages that I specify, in the same upper left corner.

Edit:

Here's a mishmash of what's I've tried so far, various lines uncommented at various times, and at this point some lines really don't make sense in the way it's presented. Only posting for street cred I guess. I'm just trying to get one small feature figured out, not asking anyone to write my program for me (which is a big difference in scope):

```
Private Sub CompanySelectComboBox_Change()
    If CompanySelectComboBox.Value <> "Select a company" Then
        ' select logo here Sheets(Sheets("TaskNew").Index + TaskSheetsComboBox.ListIndex + 1).Activate
    'Private Sub TaskSheetsComboBox_Click()
    'If TaskSheetsComboBox.Value <> "Go directly to a yellow task sheet" Then
     '   Sheets(Sheets("TaskNew").Index + TaskSheetsComboBox.ListIndex + 1).Activate
    'End If
    'End Sub
        MsgBox CompanySelectComboBox.Value
        MsgBox CompanySelectComboBox.ListIndex
        Image("Logo").Replace Image("Logo"), Sheets("Config").Image("Logo2")
        'Logo.Select
        ' another possibility:
        ' LogoPic.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
        ' another possibility:
        'Sheets("Configs").Image("Logo").Copy Before:=Sheets("TaskEnd")
        ' another possibility:
            'CodeNames of Sheets
            'Sheets("Configs").Shapes("Picture 1").Copy
            'Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Else
        ' user didn't select a company, so just keep default (Generic) for now
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And where is the piece of code you already have started with trying to solve your problem on your own? SO is not a site where you let other people write programs for you. -1

Comment: +1 for @Doc -- that might be the *ideal* of SO, but the reality...?  I wrote some of my best code on SO.  Too bad I never got to use it...  :-P

Comment: I am sorry for offending everyone. Usually just mentioning the code I've tried is enough to prove I've tried some things. I'm just asking for help with 1 small feature, not to write all of my code. I had a brain tumor in the spring and have struggled with this one feature for 2 days now and am just getting frustrated. Again, sorry for not following your rules.

Answer (score 1):

Try

http://www.officevb.com/2009/11/utilizando-o-procv-com-imagens.html

Comment: still trying, sorry I'm a bit slow. Now running to lunch, but I try to accept when I find a solution, so will get back by end of day. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried:Sheets("SwitchThisLogo").Picture("Logo1") = Offset(Sheets("Configs").Range("A30"), 0, 0, 1, 1)
and kept getting Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined (with Offset() highlighted. I don't think it'll work across multiple sheets like I want it to. The command button is on the first sheet, and needs to pull form the Configs sheet, then paste the new logo into several different sheets. Thanks anyway!

Comment: in code use `worksheet function.Offset(Sheets("Configs").Range("A30"), 0, 0, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Well, after your explanation I changed -1 to +1.  Let's break the problem into parts.

First, in your resource sheet, place your pictures in column B. Give each picture a (company name) in column A. You can adjust the row height so each picture fits into it's own row.

Then this is an example how you associate the names with those pictures:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, pic As Shape
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pictures")
For Each pic In sh.Shapes
    If pic.Type = msoPicture Then
        Debug.Print pic.TopLeftCell.Cells(1, 0) ' print the company name
    End If
Next
```

Now, you can create a combo box or user dialog from that, ask the user which company he wants and let him select a name. Here is an example function to copy a picture of a given name to the clipboard:

```
Function CopyLogoToClipboard(picName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sh As Worksheet, pic As Shape
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pictures")
    For Each pic In sh.Shapes
        If pic.Type = msoPicture And pic.TopLeftCell.Cells(1, 0) = picName Then
            pic.Copy
            CopyLogoToClipboard = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    CopyLogoToClipboard = False
End Function
```

(don't forget to check the return value when you use it).

Now, the last part is to insert the logo to the places where you want it. For example, putting it in the upper left corner on the active sheet:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste
Set pic = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
pic.Top = 0
pic.Left = 0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I came up with a different solution, but I'll try this and if it works I'll mark it correct. Haven't forgotten about it...